# How can I change the format of a Combo-Box with fill-in answers?

Tags: infopath, formatting

I'm trying to create a field with InfoPath 2013 that is a list box that allows a user to enter in their own values.  That part is simple.

Where I'm running into issue is that I want to change the formatting of the fill-in answer to be a Currency (my choice list is a list of currency amounts) and also keep the choice list of options for my users to choose from.

Is what I'm asking possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about InfoPath (since I don't use it), but through the standard List Settings area, you can click 'Create Column' and choose 'Currency' as the type.  From there, you can choose your own validation and other details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to keep the drop down choice list as well as making it a fill-in option. Creating a new column as just the currency type will make it all as a fill-in. I’ve made an update in my original question to reflect that.